# How to expose a cxf restful web service in java?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

Is there any class like `Endpoint.publish(address, implementor)` to expose the service? I am trying to deploy my application on Tomcat. Is there any class in CXF or JAX-RS to expose REST web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to annotate your APIs in the serviceBean with `javax.ws.rs` based annotations representing HTTP methods like `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc. This will expose your APIs to the JAX-RS server you will need to create in CXF configuration XML. Something like this -

```
<jaxrs:server id="base" address="/">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="provider1" />
        <ref bean="provider2" />            
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

This configuration file is the same one that gets mentioned as the `<context-param>`contextConfigLocation in your web.xml

In case you are not using Spring, the creation of the JAX-RS server can be done programmatically using:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(abc.class);

List providers = new ArrayList();
sf.setProviders(providers);
sf.setAddress(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);

server = sf.create();
```

But I don't see the point of using CXF without Spring.

Comment: Thank you @Sampada for your response. Yes using jaxrs + spring I am successfully exposing rest services. Instead of jaxrs xml   configuration  can we do this through annotation ?

Comment: No. A server needs to be created either via factory bean in java or xml configuration.

Comment: I do want to use spring but I don't want to do it through xml, but sticking with java and using `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` I get **There is an endpoint already running on /** all the time, could you expand your answer so it could be done completely without xml?