# Spring CXF configuration without xml

Tags: java, spring, web-services, annotations, cxf

I want to create a RESTfull web service using Spring + CXF without XML bean configuration. How can I convert the below XML based configuration into Java ?

**applicationBean.xml**

```
<jaxrs:server id="employeeService" address="/employeeservices">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="cxfServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Spring CXF configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  //Code for CXF need to be here
}
```

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614351/how-to-expose-a-cxf-restful-web-service-in-java/36615090#36615090

Answer (score 1):

if you are using spring-boot, here is the simplest way.

```
@Import(SpringComponentScanServer.class)
@Configuration
public class KpCxfConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(ApplicationContext context) {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/api/*");
    }

}
```

Note: your service classes needs to be annotated with **@Path** annotation

And if you are using non-spring boot application you can define servlet mapping in web.xml